# Multiple OR conditions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Why doesn't this current multiple conditional if-statement work to create a new string without the vowels?

```
public class Disemvowel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = stdin.next();
        int wordLength = word.length();
        String disemvoweledWord = "";
        for (int i=0;i<=(wordLength-1);i++){
            char currentLetter = word.charAt(i); 
            System.out.println(currentLetter);
            if (currentLetter!='a' || currentLetter!='e' || currentLetter!='i' || currentLetter!='o' || currentLetter!='u'){
                disemvoweledWord += currentLetter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(disemvoweledWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `currentLetter!='a' || currentLetter!='e'` evaluate to if the `currentLetter` is `a`?

Comment: So the whole statement will be true as long as 'a' is present, correct?

Comment: You need to do a bit of work with [de Morgan's theorems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be ANDing the conditions rather than ORing.

You only want to add the letter if it is NOT 'a' AND it is not 'e' AND it is NOT 'i' ...

To see for yourself, work out the value of your boolean expression when the letter is 'a' or 'e'.